# how to set android:targetSdkVersion="L" in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm having a warning in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. it says:

`Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.`

I learned that I should use `android:targetSdkVersion="L"` in manifest. but I'm getting an error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK  
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

when installing the apk to the emulator or device.
This is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I do not want to go to compatibility mode because my pixel formatted layout turns to sp. what should I do? I also cannot locate the build.gradle file. where should I put the `targetSdkVersion="L"`?

Comment: what device are you trying install to?

Answer (score 0):

Android L is not yet released - the latest version of Android is `20` (corresponding with Android Wear devices) - if you are not building an Android Wear app, you can ignore the warning for now and keep your target SDK at 19 or update it to 20 (which will make no difference for your phone/tablet app).